# How to process a page loaded with XMLHttpRequest with Php

Tags: php, xmlhttprequest

I want to build a site that will extract information from pages relevant to the user. Simplified view is that user select "cat", I then use XMLHttpRequest to load the content of relevant pages. I would like this content to be processed by PHP (server side). Is it possible to do?

Step by step:

1. User enter an interest
2. Ajax fetch pages content (using the client's user agent) matching the interest
3. Fetched pages are process by PHP (for data extraction)
4. Result of #3 is displayed to the user

Thanks!

Comment: Of course there is the access-control issue...
Isn't there a way to give the choice to the user if he wants to allow the request to be completed?

Answer (score -1):

Sure! You can get the whole content of the page by jQuery text or html api and send it by Ajax request to the server then the php could get the content and process it!
to ease the process I suggest to use jQuery.

[jQuery ajax api](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)
[enter link description here](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

Comment: Thank you Reza, I've clarified my question (added step by step). What I'm trying to get is a page content (fetched using Ajax) and then to have the content processed by PHP. I'm trying to find out how to send the content of the page to PHP.